# ¿ Qué es : Entry EF - EntityState.Added , EntityState.Modified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

¿Qué hace este código?

He googleado , pero no acabo de entender ¿qué hace y cómo funciona?

```
 public void EntryCtrlFactura (RNFactura factura)
 {
     Entities db = new Entities();

     ctrlFactura ctrlFactura = new ctrlFactura()
     {
         Id = factura.Id,
         ProveedorId = factura.ProveedorId,
         EstatusId = factura.EstatusId,
         SNDistribuido = factura.SNDistribuido,
         Referencia = factura.Referencia,
         Importe = factura.Importe,
         Impuesto = factura.Impuesto,
         FechaRegistro = factura.FechaRegistro,
         UsuarioReg = factura.UsuarioReg,
         FechaEnvio = factura.FechaEnvio,
         UsuarioEnv = factura.UsuarioEnv,
         Observaciones = factura.Observaciones,
         Concepto = factura.Concepto,
         CveEmpresa = factura.CveEmpresa,
         CveBodega = factura.CveBodega,
         OcId = factura.OcId
     };
                    
     using (var ctx = new Entities())
     {
         if (ctrlFactura.OcId == 0)
         {
             ctx.Entry(ctrlFactura).State = EntityState.Added;
         }
         else
         {
             ctx.Entry(ctrlFactura).State = EntityState.Modified;        
         }

         ctx.SaveChanges();
     }        
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EntityState** es una **enumeración** con **5** valores posibles e incluso combinaciones entre sus valores:

**Added**

**Modified**

**Deleted**

**Unchanged**

**Detached**

Cuando haces operaciones usando **EntityFramework** se producen cambios en la entidad donde se están realizando esos cambios, y esos cambios tienen un estado, ej. si se modificó un registro el estado de la entidad es **Modified**, o si se borró es **Deleted**.

Cuando haces **SaveChanges** al contexto, ej.:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

El **EntityFramework** recorre todas las entidades para ver su estado y si detecta que alguna cambió su estado, entonces hace efectivo este cambio y guarda dicho dato a la **base de datos**, recuerda que en **EntityFramework** hasta que no hagas **SaveChanges** no se harán efectivos los cambios en la **base de datos**.

Al marcar los cambios hechos sobre las entidades con un estado, el **EntityFramework**, sabrá exactamente que hacer con esa entidad, es decir si el estado de una entidad es **Modified**, sabe que debe modificar ese dato en la **base de datos** y si es **Added**, sabe que tiene que añadirlo, por lo que solo hará alguna acción sobre las entidades que han sido cambiadas de alguna forma, es decir las que su estado no sea **Unchanged**, esto es eficiencia, ya que si el estado de la entidad no ha cambiado, pues el **EntityFramework** sencillamente no la toca, el solo trabaja con las entidades cambiadas para registrar esos cambios en la **base de datos**.

Una vez que se hace **SaveChanges**, pues el estado de todas las entidades será **Unchanged**.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo la documentación de Microsoft, el estado ese que le pasas radica en que lo usas o no según el método que utilices para agregar o actualizar un registro en la base de datos.

```
Entities db = new Entities();

//si usas Entry, debes pasarle el estado para agregar o modificar.

    ctx.Entry(ctrlFactura).State = EntityState.Added;

//Si usas el metodo `Add` no hace falta pasarle el estado, 
  cuando apliques los cambios solo usara el estado Added
    ctx.Add(ctrlFactura) 

Db.SaveChanges();
```

De algún modo u otro ese estado esta presente en la transaccion con la base de datos.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state